# Django & PostgreSQL- Store Random Numbers in the database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In order to strengthen my basic knowledge in Django, I have decided to create something ther than a "to-do" list, I want to create a app that:

"will need to create a number of unique 6 digit codes and store in the database. This will be used to verify unique entries."

so my question is as follows:

1. How can I quickly generate and store 50 random entries in my db
2. How can I check if the user has a number that matches or not

What is the best way to approach this, I need to start thinking like a dev so I am looking for a bit of guidance and not the result, a nudge in the right direction, I have attached a mock up of the design where the user is requested to submit their "unique entry" and see if it matches to any one of them stored in the db

I am obviously reading the official django documentation too, but its not as straight forward for me to understand

Regards

Trevor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps for an idea that will help you to solve your problem,

**Step 1:** Create a model to store unique 6-digit codes. For example:

```
from django.db import models

class UniqueCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

**Step-2:** To generate and store 50 random entries in your DB. You can use the `random` module to generate the codes and the `UniqueCode` model's save method to store them in the database.

```
import random

def generate_unique_codes():
    codes = []
    for i in range(50):
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=6))
        codes.append(Code(code=code))
    UniqueCode.objects.bulk_create(codes)
```

**Step-3:** To check if the user has a number that matches or not-

```
def check_code(code):
    return UniqueCode.objects.filter(code=code).exists()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will give that a go later ! thank you for being very clear too, it really helps me to see how I should be doing this